# Hashtables not accepting String as key

Tags: java, string, key, hashtable

I don't understand why Eclipse is giving me an error regarding passing the String returned by the BufferedReader into Hashtable's put(Object,Object) method. I've read the API, I don't recognise any clues. Is it perhaps that it cannot be sure that it will return a unique String?

The String *dictionary* is set elsewhere in the file,I've stripped this down to the bit that matters - the method in question & anything happening with its variables.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Model {
     private Hashtable hash=new Hashtable();
     private String dictionary;

     public void loadWords() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br=null;

        try{        
            br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dictionary));
            do{
                hash.put(br.readLine(), new Node<E>);
            }
            while(br.readLine()!=null);

        }catch(IOException iOE){
            System.out.println("Fission mailed");
        }
        finally{
            br.close(); // Closing the buffered reader
        }
    }
```

Comment: Including the error you're seeing would be helpful in formulating an answer.

Comment: seriously you should start using [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: Consider: ConcurrentHashMap, Collections.synchronizedMap, [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), [Files.readLines](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines), [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's not problem with key it is problem with value part.
You can not add `new Node<E>` this as a Value. It must have specific type like `new Node<String>()` or `new Node<Integer>()`.

Comment: Darn, so simple. Eclipe's error warning message really wasn't helping with this & it was staring me in the face. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

\1. You are not calling the constructor of node:
hash.put(br.readLine(), new Node);

To call the default constructor you have to call the "method" with the name of the class like:

new String(); /*or*/ new Node();

\2. The generic type <E> is not seen anywhere in the declaration of the class. To use that you would have to do something like:

```
    public class Model<E> {
       private Hashtable<String, Node<E>> hash=new Hashtable<String, Node<E>> ();
```

.. so either go all the way or remove it entirely.